# Angular Use Component By Selector Array

Tags: angular

Is there a way to make this possible in angular?

```
const arrayOfComponents = ['app-component-1', 'app-component-2', 'app-component-3']

<ng-container *ngFor="let component of arrayOfComponents">
<{{ component }} [data]="data"></{{ component }}>
</ng-container>
```

instead of:

```
<app-component-1 [data]="data"></app-component-1>
<app-component-2 [data]="data"></app-component-2>
<app-component-3 [data]="data"></app-component-3>
```

Because sometime we don't know the name of the component to view and the name is sent programmatically.

In other words I am trying to make a generic component which I send an array of component names/selectors to it and it renders them.

Comment: To make what possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with the compiler. Please note it is deprecated.

**The Directive**

```
import { Compiler, Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTemplateIterator]',
})
export class TemplateIteratorDirective<T> {
  private _data: T;
  private _selectors: string[];

  @Input()
  set appTemplateIterator(value: T) {
    this._data = value;

    this.updateView();
  }

  @Input()
  set appTemplateIteratorFor(value: string[]) {
    this._selectors = value;

    this.updateView();
  }

  constructor(
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  updateView() {
    this.viewContainer.clear();

    if (this._data && this._selectors) {
      this.compiler
        .compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(AppModule)
        .then((module) => {
          const allComponentFactories = module.componentFactories;
          this._selectors
            .map((selector) =>
              allComponentFactories.find(
                (componentFactory) => componentFactory.selector === selector
              )
            )
            .filter(Boolean)
            .forEach((componentFactory) => {
              this.viewContainer
                .createComponent(componentFactory)
                .setInput('data', this._data);
            });
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ng-container
  *appTemplateIterator="'Foobar'; for: ['app-my-a', 'app-my-b']"
></ng-container>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ng7ju5?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not use interpolation in place for HTML tags.
Your best bet would be the [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)